# Change Google Maps Navigation language

Tags: languages, google-maps, android-auto

I use my phone in English (UK). But I would very much like to change the Maps navigation language to Turkish, since the English voice sucks horribly in reading Turkish place names (especially while using Android Auto). How can I do that without having to change the language of my phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that on your mobile device but is possible on your computer . [See map help](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/63471?hl=en&vid=0-784591838512-1479778696473)

Language selected on device is common to Google map. If your device is rooted , you can use [Xposed App Settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings) to change language of apps